# How to call a reactive command and wait for a side-effect before doing the subscribe action

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI and a third-party for display imaging with a undo/redo capability. I have a view model with a command to change the selected image and I would like to do the following actions when I click on my undo button:

1. Find the image on which the next undo action will occur
2. Call my command to change the selected image
3. Wait for an observable that reacts to the selected image to occur to reload the annotations on the image
4. Execute the image undo action

I have something that looks like

ViewModels:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
  public MyViewModel()
  {
    SelectImage = ReactiveCommand.Create<ImageViewModel, ImageViewModel>(phase => /* some code */);
    _selectedImage = SelectImage.ToProperty(this, x => x.SelectedImage, someDefaultValue);
  }

  private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ImageViewModel> _selectedImage ;
  public ImageViewModelSelectedImage=> _selectedImage.Value;

  public ReactiveCommand<ImageViewModel, ImageViewModel> SelectImage { get; }
}

public class ImageViewModel
{
  private object? _annot1;
  public object? Annotation1
  {
    get => _annot1;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _annot1, value);
  }

  private object? _annot2;
  public object? Annotation2
  {
    get => _annot2;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _annot2, value);
  }
}
```

View ctor:

```cs
var onAnnotationsLoaded = ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedImage.Annotation1, x => x.SelectedImage.Annotation2, (x, y) => Unit.Default)
  .Skip(1)
  .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
  .Select(_ => Observable.Start(() => LoadAnnotations(), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler));

onAnnotationsLoaded
  .Subscribe(_ => { })
  .DisposeWith(disposables);

UndoButton.Events()
  .Click
  .Select(_ => FindImageToSelect())
  .Select(image => ViewModel.SelectImage.Execute(image))
  .Switch()
  .Select(_ => onAnnotationsLoaded);
  .Select(x => x) // breakpoint here is called
  .Switch()
  .Select(x => x) // breakpoint here is called only the 2nd time undo button is clicked
  .Subscribe(_ => /* do the undo action */);
```

I have tried to replace `Observable.Start` with other methods but none are actually working as I'd like.

I am pretty sure that there is something absolutely wrong somewhere in my piping or mental model of the observables but I can't find out what.

Comment: `InvokeCommand` returns `IDisposable` not `IObservable` so I am not sure how to to the rest of the action afterward.

Comment: Await the command then? `.Select(async x => await SelectImage.Execute())` Or just do whatever the command does in the `Select`.

Comment: Not working. With or without your change the code correctly gets pass the `Select_ => onAnnotationsLoaded)` but not the following `Switch()`. Putting some break points I can see that the `WhenAnyValue` composing `onAnnotationsLoaded` is not called back.

Comment: You need to improve your example. I don't understand what you want. "*code correctly gets pass*"? And `WhenAnyValue` is called nowhere...

Comment: There you go I have updated the example to be the closest to my last attempt.